# Error when installing Rails on Mac OSx 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, nokogiri

I am trying to install Rails on my updated Mac OSx 10.10 Yosemite. 
I first used the command:

```
$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby=2.2.0
```

to install the latest RVM and Ruby versions. I also updated the gems using the command:

```
$ gem update --system
```

Until now everything looks OK but when I try to install the latest Rails version using the command:

```
$ gem install rails --version=4.2.0
```

I get this error message:

```
>   ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
    Buidling Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.2
with the following patches applied:
    - 0001-Revert-Missing-initialization-for-the-catalog-module.patch
    - 0002-Fix-missing-entities-after-CVE-2014-3660-fix.patch
```

I tried installing Nokogiri, and retried the command but got the same error message.

Any suggestion?

Comment: `gem update --system` doesn't update the gems, it updates the Rubygems code to its latest version. Use `gem update` to update the gems.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things here you can try:

[Error to install Nokogiri on OSX 10.9 Maverick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643153/error-to-install-nokogiri-on-osx-10-9-maverick)

I don't use RVM, but also had trouble installing Nokogiri on a fresh Mavericks installation a while back and resolved it with one of the alternative answers [farther down the page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21746186/254936), using `xcode-select --install`.

Also note the [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19807558/254936) answer has updated instructions for Yosemite, so I'd check out all the answers for possible solutions.