# Passing install flags when installing gems with bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, bundler

Due to Mavericks having some issues with selecting the right C-compiler sometimes when running `bundle install` I have to install some of my gems with special flags.

One example of this is I have to run: `gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries`.
This is further discussed here: [Error to install Nokogiri on OSX 10.9 Maverick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643153/error-to-install-nokogiri-on-osx-10-9-maverick)

So my question is: Is there a way to tell bundler to use system libraries when installing nokogiri? Or is there a way to tell `gem install` that it should install as "deployment"-gem.

Any other suggestions as how to solve this problem or why I'm having it would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by

`NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=1 bundle install --deployment`

Answer (score 7):

You can tell bundler about flags to use when installing gems with

```
bundle config build.nokogiri --with-system-libraries
```

This sets this as a global default, ie this setting is stored in ~/.bundle/config. To store it for the current project only, run

```
bundle config --local build.nokogiri --with-system-libraries
```

Comment: This did not work when running bundle with `--deployment` flag. I solved it using `NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=1 bundle install --deployment`. Thank you for the help with editing my question. It helped me google the problem more efficiently