# Can't create a database in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm following some tutorials of association in rails database, the first step is to create the app with `rails new newProject -B`. Then i create the two models with `rails g scaffold Father name:string` and `rails g scaffold Child name:string sex:string father:references`.

After that i try to create the database with the command `rake db:create`, but an error appears:

> Could not find nokogiri-1.6.7.1 in any of the sources Run `bundle
>   install` to install missing gems.

I run the command `bundle install` normally, but when i tried again, the same error appears.
I tried to insert in the GemFile `gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.6', '>= 1.6.7.1'` and the same error persists.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with nokogiri a couple of months ago.

I solved it by adding '-rc3' to the end of the gem version, like this:

```
gem "nokogiri", ">= 1.6.7.rc3"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem a few times before, you can try installing the gem manually using `gem install nokigiri`

Comment: take a look at this, this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643153/error-to-install-nokogiri-on-osx-10-9-maverick/19807558#19807558

Comment: The problem is that i know the gem is installed, when i run the command `gem list` , nokogiri (1.6.7.1) is listed there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try

`$bundle update`
?

Can you post the error logs to see if it is a Permissions Error or something else?

Comment: I did that, and now when i run `rake db:create`
This error appears:

NoMethodError: undefined method `>' for < 2.0, >= 1.3.0:Gem::Requirement
/vagrant/projetoAssoc/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/vagrant/projetoAssoc/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/vagrant/projetoAssoc/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)